# How to create a pop up explanation for a label in userform in vba

Tags: vba

I am looking for this feature: "when the user pauses (without clicking) the cursor over a "label" in a "userform", a small explanation window will pop up (VBA)."

I appreciate any help.

Sina

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The easiest way is to set the label's ControlTipText property.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this feature was really great.

Comment: :))))), Is there any way to have a larger font in pop-up explanation.

Comment: No practical way.  You could do it through Win API calls.

Comment: Lebans has an Access database that you can download.  In it he creates some really cool ToolTipText. [ToolTip](http://www.lebans.com/tooltip.htm)   Here is the download link: [A2kTooltipver34.zip](http://www.lebans.com/DownloadFiles/A2kTooltipver34.zip)

Comment: I have a question in the following list:                http://stackoverflow.com/q/38965880/6706528                  I appreciate it if you take look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually that's pretty simple, but it will work as a msgbox, not as a tool tip text. With that clear, let's say your label it's called "Label1" and it's inside a form, you just double click it, and use the "MouseMove" event instead of the "Click" event , here's an example of how the code goes:

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

MsgBox "message"

End Sub
```

Tell me how it goes, hope it helped you !

Comment: @sinanasiri glad to help =)