# Spelling check in user form in VBA

Tags: excel, spelling, vba

I want to check spelling in all labels that I have in a user form in VBA.

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ctrl As Object

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then


        With ctrl
            If Not Application.CheckSpelling(.Caption) Then
                .ForeColor = vbRed
                .BackColor = vbYellow
            End If
        End With


    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() Dim ctrl As Object"

Comment: That is two separate lines.  Check out my answer. I fixed it's code formatting.

Comment: What should I do: error : "end of statement expected"

Comment: Awesome!  Glad that I could help.

Comment: I appreciate it if you take a look to another question.

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091862/how-fit-a-large-userform-to-print-in-vba"