# How fit a large userform to print in VBA

Tags: vba, printing

I have a large user form in VBA, Already I have a "print" option on the form which prints half of the form.

Please let me know how I can print landscape and the whole form in 2 pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Userform PrintForm method doesn't offer any options.  Worksheet's on the other hand provide a myriad of options.

I would use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> to copy the Userform's image to the Windows ClipBoard and then paste it to a worksheet as an image.

[image]

```
Private Sub btnCopyUserformBitMap_Click()
    Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})"

    DoEvents
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

    Worksheets("Print Userform").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate it.   In the following link:          http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/fit-form-page-printing-t650323.html                                                                                           they suggest create a report, do you have any idea.

Comment: Are you using MS Access?

Comment: NO I am using excel VBA.

Comment: The article is referring to creating a MS Access Report.  It's not an option in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

PrintForm uses the default printer you have set on your system and those default settings.  Change the default to landscape and see if that works for you.