# How to print complete user form in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form in VBA, with height 515 and width 975.
And this is the code I am using to print it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Questionaire1.PrintForm
End Sub
```

This code runs perfectly, when I click the button Print form it gives me option to save the form in pdf but the this code is printing just a smaller potion of the form whereas I want to print the whole form.

[image: screenshot output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How fit a large userform to print in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091862/how-fit-a-large-userform-to-print-in-vba)

Comment: @dwirony I checked this post, but the code mentioned there does not solved my problem. I am still unable to print the complete form. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :
Declare this code in first :

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, _
     ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)
Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44
Const VK_LMENU = 164
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2
Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1
```

**EDIT :** Or if you have an error, declare this (x32 system):

```
Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, _
ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Public Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44
Public Const VK_LMENU = 164
Public Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2
Public Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1
```

And put this in your button code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    DoEvents
    keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + _
        KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_LMENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY + _
        KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    DoEvents
    Workbooks.Add
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    'added to force landscape
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape


With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 300
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = True
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

It's  work for me.
Source : https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-programming/418448-print-userform-fit-one-page.html

Screenshot : [image]

Comment: running this code I am having error, that is sub or function not defined. What is this?? Could you please help

Comment: Did you put this first code : Private Declare PtrSafe Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, _
     ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As LongPtr)
Const VK_SNAPSHOT = 44
Const VK_LMENU = 164
Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 2
Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 1

Comment: And that first block of code goes in the general space at the top of the userform's code module, right?

Comment: @Mistella that is right, I edited my answer and I added a screen shot and a new code for x32 oprating system

Comment: I have 64 bit operating system

Comment: @Shozib OK, so the first block code must be working. As Mistella said, you need to put this code in the general space, at the top of your userform's code module.

Comment: @JCGuidicelli Thankyou. having this error now, 

"Unable to set the print quality property of the page setup class"

Comment: @Shozib on the code you have this parameter: .PrintQuality = 300.
Try to delete or add in comment

Comment: I removed it. It worked but the problem is still there :(

Comment: just a small portion of the form is printing. why not the complete form??

Comment: Got it know, what it is doing. It is printing only that portion of the form which is at running time visible on the screen.

Comment: @Shozib I don't know, it's work for me.
Could try this code in a new workbook. Just add userform,  button and the code ?

Comment: I decrease the zoom from the form properties to 40, Now when I click this print button, it is printing the portion of the form which is visible in that 40% zoom, rest of the portion is neglected. 

Though in this. I mean by decreasing the overall zoom of the form I am able to print the whole form, but the problem is because of the long height of my form, when I decrease its zoom to 40, then readability of the form also decreases, as it will be harder to read such form in 40% zoom.

Any suggestion for this problem? please.

Comment: There is no problem in printing, problem is setting the printing area actually

Comment: What is the result if you change all margin to 0 (.LeftMargin  to .FooterMargin ) ?

Comment: let me check it

Comment: @JCGuidicelli nothing happened. Problem is still there

Comment: If you have any user form, set its properties:
Height 576
Width 990

Comment: with zoom 100%, then apply this code (which you shared) for printing. You will see what is happening. Thanks